# How to check if a directory doesn't exist in make and create it

Tags: file, compilation, makefile

In my project's directory, I have some subdirs: `code/`, `export/`, `docs/` and `object/`. What `make` does is simply compile all the files from the code dir, and put the .o files into the object dir.

The problem is, I told git to ignore all .o files, because I don't want them uploaded, so it doesn't track the object dir either. I'm actually OK with that, I don't want the `object/` uploaded to my GitHub account as well, but with the current solution (which is a simple empty text file inside the `object/` dir), the directory does get uploaded and needs to be present before the build (the makefile just assumes it's there).

This doesn't really seem like the best solution, so is there a way to check if a directory doesn't exist before the build in a make file, and create it if so? This would allow for the object dir not to be present when the make command is called, and created afterwards.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just have a target for it:

```
object/%.o: code/%.cc object
    compile $< somehow...

object:
    mkdir $@
```

You have to be a little more careful if you want to guard against the possibility of a file called "object", but that's the basic idea.

Comment: It is often preferable to use an order-only prerequisite for this (that is, use `code/%.cc | object`), so that `object` does not affect `$^`.

Comment: @Idelic: neat trick, I didn't know that `$^` didn't include order-only preqs. Thanks!

Comment: So, I couldn't for example have a target called "debug" and a folder called "debug". . .

Comment: this does not work as intended, as the timestamp of the object directory will change when any object if added to it. see the other answer.

Answer (score 39):

The only correct way to do this is with **order-only-prerequisites**, see: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html. Note the **|** in the snippet.

If you don't use order-only-prerequisites each modification (e.g. coping or creating a file) in that directory will trigger the rule that **depends** on the directory-creation target again!

```
object/%.o: code/%.cc | object
    compile $< somehow...

object:
    mkdir -p $@
```

Comment: Good point! That way it would be created just if it not exist yet, instead of try to create every time the rule is execute (for each object file)

Answer (score 21):

Insert a mkdir command in the target.

```
object/%.o : code/%.cc
    @mkdir -p object
    compile $< somehow...
```

The '-p' results in no error if the directory already exists.

Comment: Works but less optimal: forks a shell process every time as opposed to just when required.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the $(@D) make variable to create the directory of the target. $(@D) refers to the directory of the target. So you can use:

```
out/%.o: src/%.c
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

This also works great if the folder is a variable, like:

```
OBJ:=objects

$(OBJ)/%.o: src/%.c
   mkdir -p $(@D)
   $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

With $(@D) you can change the OBJ variable and you won't need to change also the mkdir line in the recipe.